# How to use global flag in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am reading about RegExp. I have a small problem with me now

```
var text = "cat, bat, fat";
var pattern = /.at/gi;
var matches = pattern.exec(text);
```

By executing this for the first time I am getting only one match that is cat when i execute the second time i am getting bat.  I have specified the global flag but till its giving only one at a time.Am i specifying it wrongly or thats the way regexp works?

Comment: This is how `g` works with `exec`. If you hadn't used `g` you would always get the first match. But `g` behaves differently for all the different regex functions (like `test`, `match` and `search`)

Comment: Have a look at the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = "cat, bat, fat";
var pattern = /.at/g;
var matches = text.match(pattern);
```